Bootstrap modal in .NET Core 8 is not rendered properly
I have a simple bootstrap modal but it is not showing properly in a .NET Core 8 project, all other bootstrap elements in my application are working properly, I installed bootstrap as client-side library and also CSS and related JS are added to the _Layout page. It seems some styling and JavaScript is missing but all required css/javascripts are added in _Layout and working for other bootstrap element in various pages as well as bootstrap tables.
This is what I am getting:

_Layout:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link href="~/bootstrap-table/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/bootstrap-table/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>

The modal page code:
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
});

I made sure that Bootstrap is added to my project and it is working for all other bootstrap elements in various pages but the modal.

It's 2024, you don't need jQuery.

Please post the raw rendered HTML of of those <link and <script elements. I want to see how the ~/ is being resolved.

Also, as it's (also) 2024, you don't need any JS libraries for modal dialogs - it's all native HTML now: just use <dialog> - so all you need is trivial DOM-only JS to toggle the open attribute and maybe some CSS styles.

Bugs caused by the bootstrap version.It is written in the same way as v 4.6.0  but .net 8  use v5.1.0
Official document address： https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/modal/
Here's an example：
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
    Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h1>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

The results are as follows:

